# How to use mail command from within Windows Linux Subsystem?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, sendmail

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 from within WSL. I installed postfix, sendmail and mailutils.

After some headaches I got the mail command to run without errors but I'm not getting the emails I'm sending myself at gmail... and I can't see any log files anywhere either :(

Did someone go through this?

Thanks

Comment: This [ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/59602/where-to-check-log-of-sendmail) may be of some small help. But this question likely needs any logs you may have (as well as details about any other troubleshooting steps you may have taken) to be (potentially) answerable. Also, any information you may have about your DNS setup (specifically TXT records) would probably be useful as well.

Comment: I tried to get log files from /var/log/mail.log but there's nothing there... @Anaksunaman what information about DNS setup should I look for?

Answer (score 1):

I just completed a succesful test. The problem I found is that the postfix service, although correctly installed, was not started :(

I started the service and was finally able to send an email to @yahoo and got it (Although in spam)

Comment: How did you start it?

Comment: I don't remember exactly but I believe I simply run ```sudo service postfix start```